# rc.local is not executed on tartup in Ubuntu Server 13.04

Tags: 13.04, server, startup

I'm trying to add some `iptables` rules on startup for my VPN service in `rc.local`.
my `rc.local` file is:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -j REJECT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source #######
exit 0
```

it is executable:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 529 Nov 24 06:01 /etc/rc.local
```

But it doesn't run on startup! (None of rules are added!)

What is the problem?
How Can make it run on startup?

Comment: Are you sure your `rc.local` is not executed? It is possible that at the time of execution `iptables` is not ready to accept rules yet.

Comment: @drc: No, I'm not! (This works on another 13.04 server without problem! I just have the problem on this one) How can I find out? if this is the problem, how can I insert these rules on startup?